# C# No overload for method when using dynamic on inherited interface

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.8

Working on adding a shim layer over a c# library and came across an interesting issue. I have an existing interface that contains a dynamic parameter on one of the methods. When I call the method when using the child interface I get a runtime error of

> "'FullFramework.IFoo2' does not contain a definition for "Test"

but if I call the method after casting to the base interface everything works correctly. I am seeing the issue on full framework 4.8.1, but not in .net core 3.1. I was able to avoid the error by hiding the method in question on the child interface, but curious if this is a known issue/is there a better way to work around it?

```
namespace FullFramework
{

    public interface IFoo
    {
        int Test(string param1, dynamic bar);
    }

    public interface IFoo2 : IFoo
    {

    }

    public class FooImpl : IFoo2
    {
        public int Test(string param1, dynamic bar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bar.ToString());
            return param1.Length;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new { };
            var db = new FooImpl();
            MethodCallWorking(db, x);
            MethodCall(db, x);
        }

        public static void MethodCall(IFoo2 foo, dynamic x)
        {
            foo.Test("Select", x);
        }

        public static void MethodCallWorking(IFoo foo, dynamic x)
        {
            foo.Test("Select", x);
        }
    }
}
```